# How to create a gender ratio table without one-hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have two dataframes in Python, one with customer data and one with lists of purchased items. I want to create a table that shows the gender ratio for each item and median age.

## Table 1 (which items that each customer owns) :

| Customer_ID | Item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `[4, 99, 833]` |
| 2 | `[4, 44, 5 383, 11, 1000]` |
| 3 | `[3, 1, 5]` |
| 4 | `[40, 334, 884, 1]` |

## Table 2 (Customer Data):

| Customer_ID | Gender | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `M` | `50` |
| 2 | `F` | `40` |
| 3 | `M` | `33` |
| 4 | `F` | `29` |

## Desired Output:

| Item | Gender_Distribution_M [%] | Gender_Distribution_F [%] | Median_Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x% | y% | z |
| ..... | . | . | . |

One approach that I can think of is to do One-Hot encoding for all the items, but is there any easier way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, this should work for you:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Customer_ID': range(1, 5), 'Item': [[4, 99, 833], [4, 44, 5, 383, 11, 1000], [3, 1, 5], [40, 334, 884, 1]]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Customer_ID': range(1, 5), 'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'F'], 'Age': [50, 40, 33, 29]})
df3 = pd.merge(df1.explode('Item'), df2, how='left', on='Customer_ID')

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Gender_Distribution_M [%]'] = df3.groupby('Item').Gender.value_counts().unstack().M.div(df3.groupby('Item').Gender.value_counts().unstack().M.add(df3.groupby('Item').Gender.value_counts().unstack().F, fill_value=0), fill_value=0).mul(100)
df['Gender_Distribution_F [%]'] = df3.groupby('Item').Gender.value_counts().unstack().F.div(df3.groupby('Item').Gender.value_counts().unstack().M.add(df3.groupby('Item').Gender.value_counts().unstack().F, fill_value=0), fill_value=0).mul(100)
df['Median_Age'] = df3.groupby('Item').Age.median()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      Gender_Distribution_M [%]  Gender_Distribution_F [%]  Median_Age
Item                                                                  
1                          50.0                       50.0        31.0
3                         100.0                        0.0        33.0
4                          50.0                       50.0        45.0
5                          50.0                       50.0        36.5
11                          0.0                      100.0        40.0
40                          0.0                      100.0        29.0
44                          0.0                      100.0        40.0
99                        100.0                        0.0        50.0
334                         0.0                      100.0        29.0
383                         0.0                      100.0        40.0
833                       100.0                        0.0        50.0
884                         0.0                      100.0        29.0
1000                        0.0                      100.0        40.0
```

Comment: Hi again, 
Thank you I accepted your answer :)

However, I have one last question. In my case, the final df is not indexed in the same way as df3. How can I add a column to df with the median ages from df3, and map the Item Number as well.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I understand your use case, but in general you can merge two dataframes this way: `df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='id_col_df1', right_on='id_cold_df2'`. When needed you can reset the index (index becomes a column) this way: `df.reset_index()`.